# How to remove college information from a Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, developer-story

My college information is public on my Stack Overflow page and is not available on my other Stack Exchange accounts. This means that I might have added that information sometime in the past to my Stack Overflow page only. I can't seem to find the option to remove that information. Please don't say go to your profile and click on the edit button. There is no option in the edit menu to edit college information.

I used to sign in to Stack Overflow using my Google account, and it might be possible that my Google account had this information. I would also like to unlink my Google account from Stack Overflow preferences and I am unable to find the option for that as well.

Please help.

A screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image: The personal information I want to hide]

Comment: What college information are you talking about? Do you mean your [developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/6712710)

Comment: @RobertLongson It could be information from my developer story though I did not find any option to remove this from there as well. I have added a screenshot for the information I want to remove.

Comment: Go to your [developer story,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/6712710) click the edit on the top right and delete your title.

Comment: @rene I have title field blank in both edit section and developer story section. So I put "NA" there and my college information disappeared and NA came there. Then I removed NA from the edit section and made title field blank again and my college information reappeared. Is it a bug?

Comment: I've migrated this because it's about the developer story elements, which are SO-specific.

Comment: @as2d3 have you put an end date in for your college information?

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't think I put anything anywhere. But if I had put my college information in some field long time back, then I think I might have put 2019 as the end date for my college information.

Comment: @as2d3 Did your hidden title disapear? I submitted a request to delete my data as suggested by Jeremy on my post,but it's still waiting to be approved. However, I was deleting one information from my profile, and when I tested to leave a blank on my title, the old one wasn't displayed. i'm not sure if it's because something was fixed, because I edited multiple fields, because they took care of my request but didn't validated yet or for any others reasons

Comment: @JackRed Yes, the title disappeared. They probably fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

I am answering my own question because this seems to be a bug or some feature which is not so valid in my case I guess.

Some information about my SO account:

1. I created my account 2-3 years back
2. I used the Google sign-in method initially, but I don't use it anymore.
3. I might have created my title field in my developer story, but it was empty when I checked before writing this answer.

What I did:
Since the title field was initially blank in both edit section and developer story section, I was unable to understand why my college information was appearing in profile. I checked everywhere in edit section but did not find anything related to this. I modified my title field to "NA" and then my college information was gone and NA appeared there as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: NA]

Now, I removed the "NA" from the title field and made it blank again and my college information reappeared. I think it is pulling that information from some database whose field is not made editable in the edit section or is removed in some later version and we can't find it anymore.

I request developers to please refactor the code of Stack Overflow and keep the title field away from other fields. Make it simple to edit and understand.

Comment: Refactoring does not change the (external) behaviour (that is the whole point of refactoring).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes but the developers mentioned in some answer that the code is really clumsily written and they know about a few more similar bugs but they don't want to change the code right now because it can affect some other part of the website. Here is the link to what I am referring to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287892/548316

Comment: If you don't like NA, can you use a space or a non breakable space or the like for now?

Comment: @B.Go Cannot use space but I am using "-" for now.