# Where does the current job position displayed on my profile come from?

Tags: support, profile-page

I have my current position filled out on my profile:

[image: Current Position field on my profile]

What's weird is that I'm not sure where this info comes from.

Firstly, I checked my Profile Settings, but it says that no title has been set:

[image: "No title has been set" placeholder text for Title under Profile Settings]

After that, I checked my Developer Story, but it's empty (click to enlarge):

[image: Empty Developer Story]

I also looked at my Developer Story profile settings ([as suggested by rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385920/3151675#comment702406_385920)), but the Title field is not filled out there either (click to enlarge):

[image: Title field is empty under Edit Developer Story]

I searched for other possibly related settings, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Also, it's important to mention that I don't recall deleting this info from my profile, unlike the situation [described in this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385813/3151675) ([suggested by BDL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385920/3151675#comment702405_385920)).

Help me solve this mystery!

<sup>BTW I'm using [Dark Reader for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en). I'm in no way affiliated with them, just wanted to help others looking for this theme.</sup>

Comment: Maybe related to this: [Don't show old title when a user removes it from the profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385813/dont-show-old-title-when-a-user-removes-it-from-the-profile)

Comment: *I checked my Developer Story, but it's empty* Well. I can edit that Developer Story page (as it has an Edit button) and that reveals a title field.

Comment: There have been a lot of complaints from users that once had selected a title or Jobs profile, then tried to reset it back to make it blank.  Doesn't work, the machine remembers the original entry.  Why this is hard to fix is very murky.  Workaround is to set the title to something innocuous, like "N/A" or "This line is intentionally blank".

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385886/how-to-remove-college-information-from-a-stack-overflow-profile

Comment: @rene That field is empty as well. I updated my question to include that info.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the screenshot, Please take the advice from @HansPassant as it is for now your only option to get around that issue.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated my question with some additional info. Basically, I don't recall removing this information from my profile (and I don't even want/wanted to).

Comment: Nobody ever remembers it, they entered it too long ago.  We probably do need somebody to scream bloody murder about unintentional disclosure of private information to get this bug fixed.  Could be you.

Comment: Give this an inflammatory title like "Stack Overflow holds onto our private information without disclosure or recourse", throw in some indirect accusations of malicious intent, and you too could have +500 votes in a week... and the company will continue to ignore it. They don't appear to consider themselves *at all* accountable to their users any more.

Comment: @Jeremy You forgot to recommend Twitter

Comment: @TamásSengel Did your hidden title disapear? I submitted a request to delete my data as suggested by Jeremy on my post,but it's still waiting to be approved. However, I was deleting one information from my profile, and when I tested to leave a blank on my title, the old one wasn't displayed. i'm not sure if it's because something was fixed, because I edited multiple fields, because they took care of my request but didn't validated yet or for any other reason

Comment: @JackRed Hmmm, yes, it *did* disappear. Thanks for the notice!